# ROBLOX. So, this function is only running once and i don't know why. Does anyone know why?

Tags: lua, roblox

This is the script. I don't know why but it's only running once.

```
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local localplayer = players.LocalPlayer
local char = localplayer.Character
local hum = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local cam = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera
local MenuCamera = game.Workspace.MenuRoom.MenuCamera

hum.Died:Connect(function()
    wait(1.5)
    script.Parent.DeathScreen.Visible = true
    repeat
        cam.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
    until cam.CameraType == Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
    cam.CFrame = MenuCamera.CFrame
    wait(2)
    script.Parent.DeathScreen.Visible = false
end)
```

It just doesn't run the script when i die.

Comment: It doesn't run the script when i die the second time*

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be in PlayerGui, for which I'm assuming you've got `ResetOnSpawn` in the properties tab turned off. You either need to turn that on so that whenever the player character dies, this script is created and runs again; OR you need to move all of your character related code into a function that is run every time a new character is created, using `Player.CharacterAdded`.

The issue is that once your player's character dies, your assignments from the top of your script no longer point to anything. You need to be reassigning and updating them.

Thanks to Kylaaa for pointing out that by the time the script executes, the `CharacterAdded` event might have already been fired. I typically handle this with a flag (for client) or some transient table (for server).

```lua
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local localplayer = players.LocalPlayer

local cam = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera
local MenuCamera = game.Workspace.MenuRoom.MenuCamera

local playerAlreadyLoaded = player.Character -- store for use later

local function handleDeath(char)
    local hum = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

    hum.Died:Connect(function()
        wait(1.5)
        script.Parent.DeathScreen.Visible = true
        repeat
            cam.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
        until cam.CameraType == Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
        cam.CFrame = MenuCamera.CFrame
        wait(2)
        script.Parent.DeathScreen.Visible = false
    end)
end

localplayer.CharacterAdded:Connect(handleDeath)

if playerAlreadyLoaded then
    handleDeath(playerAlreadyLoaded)
end
```

If the goal of the `repeat until` is to wait for the player to enter the menu again, then you should remove that and instead handle setting the CameraType and removing the death screen wherever you're handling the rest of your menu.

```lua
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local localplayer = players.LocalPlayer

local cam = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera
local MenuCamera = game.Workspace.MenuRoom.MenuCamera

local playerAlreadyLoaded = player.Character -- store for use later

localplayer.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
    local hum = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

    hum.Died:Connect(function()
        task.wait(1.5)
        script.Parent.DeathScreen.Visible = true
        -- handle your other stuff wherever you're handling the rest of the main menu.
    end)
end)

if playerAlreadyLoaded then
    handleDeath(playerAlreadyLoaded)
end
```

Honestly, this entire process should be handled along with your main menu. It'd be easier and more efficient.

Comment: Since the original code sample works once, it might be safe to assume that by the time the script executes, the character model already exists in the workspace, so the `CharacterAdded` event has already fired. So you might have a timing issue with your solution.   It might be a good idea to move the `CharacterAdded` connection to a local function and reusing it when checking `if localplayer.Character then  characterAddedFunction(localplayer.Character) end` That way you'll listen for character respawns, while also catching any deaths of the existing character model.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead of that code, there is no need for that repeat loop but you can add checks to ensure that the code runs at a time when it can.

Also turn on ResetOnSpawn this will fix your issue.

```
    local players = game:GetService("Players")
    local localplayer = players.LocalPlayer
    local char = localplayer.Character or localplayer.CharacterAdded:Wait()  -- Handle character respawn
    local hum = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    local cam = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera
    local MenuCamera = game.Workspace.MenuRoom.MenuCamera

    hum.Died:Connect(function()
        print("Death event triggered!")  -- Debugging
        wait(1.5)
        script.Parent.DeathScreen.Visible = true

        cam.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
        cam.CFrame = MenuCamera.CFrame

        wait(2)
        script.Parent.DeathScreen.Visible = false
    end)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. But same problem it only runs once and then it doesn't run anymore.

Comment: That's a problem on your end then, view your scripts and try to fix, I can't examine any errors in the script.

Comment: Put this script that should be a LocalScript  in StarterPlayerScripts and change the paths in the script to WaitForChild('PlayerGui') paths

Comment: Only thing I can say to help not enough context :c